# ReportViewer not working on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I just adquired the VS 2012 and I tryed to open my projects I made using VS 2010.
But now, the `ReportViewer` is not working, it shows up but with NO DATA.
my code are OK, my querys are OK, everything about this are OK, I'm sure !!

Because it's not working only now in the `Visual Studio 2012`, anyone would know what could I do ?

I tried to remove some lines from my web.config:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>  

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
```

I also tried to delete my current ReportViewer and Create a new one, didn't work neither...

Obs: I'm not posting any code here because I have no need to correct my code, it's ok, I'm sure ! I just need know why it's not working on VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have updated your aspx page hosting the reportviewer with the reference to the version 11.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```